# DIVIDIR TEXTO POR TAMAÑO

Tags: python-3.x

soy un poco nuevo en pyhton y queria peguntar si alguno de ustedes sabe como dividir un string por tamaño en una lista, es decir que cada tantos caracteres se vayan guardando en una lista, por ejemplo:
x = '123456789' y para este ejemplo quisiera hacer esto
lista = ['12','34','56',78',9] cada dos caracteres se van guardando y el ultimo pues como solo es uno que se guarde solo tengo en codigo esto:

```
x = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz '
for i in range(0,len(x),5):
    if i+5 < len(x):
        for j in range(i,i+5):
            lista.append(x[:i+5])
            print(lista)
['abcde']
['abcde', 'abcde']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'tuvwx']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx']
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'fghij', 'fghij', 'fghij', 
'fghij', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 
'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'opqrs', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx', 'tuvwx', 
'tuvwx']
```

esa es la respuesta como les dije soy nuevo y si me pueden ayudar les agradeceria

Comment: Lectura obligatoria mi estimado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
x = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz '
lista=[]
c=0
cad = ""
for i in x: #itera todos los caracteres
    cad=cad + i #concatena
    c = c + 1
    if(c == 5):
        lista.append(cad)
        c = 0
        cad = ""
lista.append(cad)
print(lista)




output:
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmnñ', 'opqrs', 'tuvwx', 'yz ']
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, agrega por favor una explicación de lo que realiza el código, comenta de que forma ayudaría a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [answer], saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero ya entiendo mejor algunas cosas